# I need to customize the open source couch app in couchdb that is index.html for my project requirement. Kindly help me in this

Tags: couchdb, acra, couchapp, acralyzer

I'm working on couchdb due to my project requirement to have crash analytics.
Using Acra and Acralyser to implement this concept. I need to customize the Acralyzer ie couchapp based on my Scope. Kindly help me how to customize the web application in couchdb.If we have any open source ide, please suggest me to edit the attachements of couchdb.

Comment: it is not free one. It is paid

Answer (score 1):

Acralyser is implemented with CouchDB as default. If you are looking for an IDE, it is off-topic for stackoverflow.

If you are looking to edit these files, just open in notepad or any text editor(or Notepad++).

It was hard understanding this question, so if I misunderstood you, comment and I will update the answer